# Does Ubuntu Advantage Advanced services support Ubuntu Version 13.04?

Tags: ubuntu-advantage

Does Ubuntu Advantage Advanced services support Ubuntu Version 13.04? Also, I keep getting an error stating that this post does not meet our quality standards. Please explain WHY?

Comment: There's some sort of automated scanning that posts are subjected to.

Answer (score 0):

Any version of Ubuntu currently in the active part of its lifecycle (see chart at [LTS | Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) ) can be selected by an Ubuntu Advantage customer, and will be supported by Canonical.

So the answer is Yes, 13.04 is currently covered by Ubuntu Advantage.